# Building mariadb-connector-c on OSX

Tags: macos, mariadb, ninja, mariadb-connector-c

I'm trying to build the [C connector for MariaDB](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c) on the latest OSX but it seems to fail with an error related to SSL. I installed SSL using Macports (/opt/local/lib/openssl) and added an include that points to it:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(tests PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

but building it returns the same error:

```
~/chi/databaseclient/cpp/ninja/mariadb-connector-c-src
⟩ ninja
[81/115] Building C object libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/inflate.c.o
zlib/inflate.c:1475:61: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined [-Wshift-negative-value]
    if (strm == Z_NULL || strm->state == Z_NULL) return -1L << 16;
                                                        ~~~ ^
1 warning generated.
[89/115] Linking C shared library libmariadb/libmariadb.3.dylib
FAILED: libmariadb/libmariadb.3.dylib 
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -DDBUG_OFF -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -compatibility_version 3.0.0 -current_version 3.0.0 -o libmariadb/libmariadb.3.dylib -install_name /Users/ruihpacheco/chi/databaseclient/cpp/ninja/mariadb-connector-c-src/libmariadb/libmariadb.3.dylib libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/plugins/auth/my_auth.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/plugins/auth/old_password.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/plugins/pvio/pvio_socket.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_array.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_charset.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_hash.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_net.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/mariadb_charset.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_time.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_default.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_errmsg.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/mariadb_lib.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_list.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_pvio.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_tls.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_alloc.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_compress.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_init.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_password.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_ll2str.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_sha1.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/mariadb_stmt.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_loaddata.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_stmt_codec.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_string.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_dtoa.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_client_plugin.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_io.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/secure/openssl.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/adler32.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/compress.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/crc32.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/deflate.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/gzclose.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/gzlib.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/gzread.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/gzwrite.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/infback.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/inffast.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/inflate.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/inftrees.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/trees.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/uncompr.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/__/zlib/zutil.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/mariadb_dyncol.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/mariadb_async.c.o libmariadb/CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/ma_context.c.o  /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib && :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_X509_check_host", referenced from:
      _ma_tls_verify_server_cert in openssl.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[91/115] Building C object unittest/libmariadb/CMakeFiles/ps_bugs.dir/ps_bugs.c.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Looks like you're linking against the system ssl:  /usr/lib/libssl.dylib on the link command, but it sounds like you're including a non-system ssl library.  So it's certainly possible there is a mismatch of some kind.

Try using the system ssl for both compilation and linking, or use the brew installed one, but don't mix them.

Comment: This is not mine, it's MariaDB's.

Comment: sorry, bad phrasing.  s/you're/it's/

Comment: My point about you adding a macports openSSL distro that's not being used during linking still stands.  I'm actually not sure it's being used as an include either.  Take out your extra include thing for the macports openssl and post the build error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically CMake is, for some reason, using Macports header files but system libraries.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB Connector/C works correctly with all supported OpenSSL versions.

The error 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64  "_X509_check_host"' indicates that you use an older OpenSSL version which is not supported anymore. X509_check_host was introduced in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Please update your OpenSSL version to 1.0.2 or newer. See also https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html

Comment: I have 1.0.2:

> openssl version                                                                                                                                                                   
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018